# Array values not showing up in custom table cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am making a simple weather app and my table view is supposed to show the weeks forecast by showing the day on the left side and the high temp on the right side. My cellForRowAtIndexpath is below. It correctly displays the dayarray in my custom daylabel but the maxarray which contains max temperatures doesn't show up. When I print out the max array values it looks correct and all the numbers are listed there but still does not show up. If I just hard code a value in that text label like "Test" then that will show up but the array doesn't.

```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DailyWeatherTableViewCell

      cell.daylabel.text = dayarray[indexPath.row] as? String

      cell.maxlabel.text = maxarray[indexPath.row] as? String

      return cell
```

UPDATE: My array is set up like this:

```
dayarray = [dateString1,dateString2, dateString3, dateString4, dateString5, dateString6, dateString7]

maxarray = [max1int, max2int, max3int, max4int, max5int, max6int, max7int]
```

Its kind of complicated where these values come from but if I print out maxarray, it looks like this:

100
100
92
90
90
89
89

Comment: have you set the tableview `datasource`

Comment: Yes, I did via clicking and dragging the tableview to the table view controller.

Comment: I think you also need to show your code where you initialise the array or fetch API data into array. If you are using asynchronous fetch such as Alamofire, you need to save data into array in the completion method, then need to reload tableView

Comment: Updated original question to include array initialization

Comment: Share the frames for cell.daylabel and cell.maxlabel

Comment: added my answer below @Martheli

Comment: @h44f33z that solved me problem thank you! What is the difference between what I did and what you did? Why did my way cause the value to be nil when converting?

Comment: I updated my answer with explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you cast the `Int` to `String` cause the value to nil. Try change to below instead:

```
cell.maxlabel.text = String(maxarray[indexPath.row])
```

The different is that `String()` is create an object of string from the `Int` value. while the `as?` operator normally used when you have different type of objects in your array and you want to cast it to specific type. for example

```
let arr = [1, 21, 3, 5, "Hello world", 1, 2, "food"]

for element in arr {
    if let stringValue = element as? String {
        print(stringValue)
    }
    else if let intValue = element as? Int {
        print (intValue)
    }

}
```

Comment: Also can use `"\(maxarray[indexPath.row])"`